# Yotube video embeddign

Tags: html, youtube

I am trying to embedd youtube video and i have just coppied what youtube gave me

```
 <iframe
        width="560"
        height="315"
        src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/w3jLJU7DT5E"
        title="YouTube video player"
        frameborder="0"
        allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in- 
        picture"
        allowfullscreen>
</iframe>
```

but i am getting a bunch of error in my chrome console

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/id:1 

Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT static.doubleclick.net/instream/ad_status.js:1 

Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT   www.youtube.com/generate_204?sdc-Mg:1 

Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT 
 i.ytimg.com/vi_webp/w3jLJU7DT5E/maxresdefault.webp:1 

Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED
www.youtube.com/youtubei/v1/log_event?alt=json&key=AIzaSyAO_FJ2SlqU8Q4STEHLGCilw_Y9_11qcW8:1
 
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT
www.youtube.com/youtubei/v1/log_event?alt=json&key=AIzaSyAO_FJ2SlqU8Q4STEHLGCilw_Y9_11qcW8:1
 
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT
www.youtube.com/youtubei/v1/log_event?alt=json&key=AIzaSyAO_FJ2SlqU8Q4STEHLGCilw_Y9_11qcW8:1

Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT
www.youtube.com/youtubei/v1/log_event?alt=json&key=AIzaSyAO_FJ2SlqU8Q4STEHLGCilw_Y9_11qcW8:1 

Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT  www.youtube.com/youtubei/v1/log_event?alt=json&key=AIzaSyAO_FJ2SlqU8Q4STEHLGCilw_Y9_11qcW8:1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> the “failed to load resource” error is the result of a missing server file. A URL typo might also cause it. More commonly, however, a browser extension has blocked a request.

> Ad blockers and other content moderators can interfere with regular parts of a webpage. These tools work by searching a site for specific words and patterns. Any similarities can mean that your files get caught up in the blocklist.

You need to:

- Reset Your Browser to the Default Settings
- Rename Any Problematic
- Files Debug Your Page Using an Ad Blocker
- Allowlist the Website (If
  You’re a Visitor)

Comment: Yes! actually i was using brave browsers which block ads so i allowed everything and now there is no errors in by console. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

"ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT" sounds like it might be a problem with the client sight of your website and not with your website/youtube itself.

Do you have an adblock servive running? If so try disabling it.
Maybe you have some other browser extension that might temper with the sites you are visiting/what is being loaded.

Comment: I got it. actually i was using the brave browser and after reading this i allowed everything now the errors are gone. 

Answer (score -1):

You are propabily using ADBLOCK and you are using AUTOPLAY ON so the ADBLOCK blocks your autoplay.

But thats not the only error, and to fix that i changed the URL on my project and it worked for me.

Try change the url from 'src' to:

src="https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/{video_id}"

Full code:

```
<iframe
    width="560"
    height="315"
    src="https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/w3jLJU7DT5E"
    title="YouTube video player"
    frameborder="0"
    allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; 
    picture-in- 
    picture"
    allowfullscreen>
</iframe>
```